# Variable in commands in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I wrote program that should write words from example.txt from the longest to the shortest. I don't know how exactly `'^.{$v}$'` should look like to make it work?

```
#!/bin/bash
v=30

while [ $v -gt 0 ] ; do
    grep -P '^.{$v}$' example.txt 
    v=$(($v - 1))
done
```

I tried:

- `${v}`
- `$v`
- `"$v"`

It is my first question, sorry for any mistake :)

Comment: not bad for a first Q, at least you have tried to solve  your problem. In the future (not so much for this Q), it is very helpful to include A.a small set of sample data that covers all the cases you expect to process plus 1 item that will NOT be processed ; B. the required output from that input, including the record that didn't get processed C. your code/current output/error messages. D. your thoughts on why your code should work (we'll help you fix your understanding of how things work). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is not how you'd approach this problem in shell. Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to learn some of the issues and then this is how you'd really do what you're trying to do in a shell script:

```
$ cat file
now
is
the
winter
of
our
discontent

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length($0), NR, $0}' file | sort -k1rn -k2n | cut -f3-
discontent
winter
now
the
our
is
of
```

To understand what that's doing, look at the awk output:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length($0), NR, $0}' file
3       1       now
2       2       is
3       3       the
6       4       winter
2       5       of
3       6       our
10      7       discontent
```

The first number is the length of each line and the second number is the order the lines appeared in the input file so when we come to sort it:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length($0), NR, $0}' file | sort -k1rn -k2n
10      7       discontent
6       4       winter
3       1       now
3       3       the
3       6       our
2       2       is
2       5       of
```

we can sort by length (longest first) with `-k1rn` but retain the order from the input file for lines that are the same length by adding `-k2n`. Then the `cut` just removes the 2 leading numbers that `awk` added for `sort` to use.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
grep -P "^.{$v}$" example.txt
```